# Using cv::imshow("name",Mat) on different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, gtk

I am getting different video streams from several cameras, which I would like to see in parallel using OpenCV imshow. The imageCapture function is very straightforward and causes no trouble when running alone. However, when I run more than one thread, I get Gtk errors.

The threading is done like:

```
std::thread capture1 (captureImages,hCams.at(0),cSettingsVector.at(0));
std::thread capture2 (captureImages,hCams.at(1),cSettingsVector.at(1));
capture1.join();
capture2.join();
```

And the captureImages function:

```
std::cout << std::endl<< std::endl << "Entering capture function " << std::endl;
int nRet;
char* imgMem;
int memId;
void *pMem;

int bitsPerPixel;
if (cSettings.color == true)
{
    bitsPerPixel = 24;
}
else
{
    bitsPerPixel = 8;
}
char buffer[256];
sprintf(buffer,"Calling AllocImageMem with handler %i on %s", hCam, cSettings.SN.c_str());
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
nRet = is_AllocImageMem(hCam, cSettings.AOI.s32Width, cSettings.AOI.s32Height, bitsPerPixel, &imgMem, &memId);
nRet = is_SetImageMem (hCam, imgMem, memId);
nRet = is_CaptureVideo(hCam,IS_DONT_WAIT);

unsigned int iframe(0);
for(;;)
{

    nRet = is_GetImageMem(hCam, &pMem);
    cv::Mat frame;
    if (cSettings.color == true)
    {
        cv::Mat colorFrame(cv::Size(cSettings.AOI.s32Width, cSettings.AOI.s32Height),CV_8UC3,pMem);
        frame = colorFrame;
    }
    else
    {
        cv::Mat grayFrame(cv::Size(cSettings.AOI.s32Width, cSettings.AOI.s32Height),CV_8UC1,pMem);
        frame = grayFrame;
    }

    cv::namedWindow(cSettings.SN,cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);
    cv::imshow(cSettings.SN,frame);
    cv::waitKey(1);

    char buffer[128];

    sprintf(buffer,"/home/scanner3d/videoCapture/%i-%s.png",iframe,cSettings.SN.c_str());
    cv::imwrite(buffer,frame);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    iframe ++;
}
sprintf(buffer,"Process with handle %i on %s is done.", hCam, cSettings.SN.c_str());
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

To wrap it up, here are the errors:

```
(4103086391:781): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()

(4103086391:781): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GTypeModule'

(4103086391:781): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(4103086391:781): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(4103086391:781): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(4103086391:781): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GTypeModule'

(4103086391:781): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(4103086391:781): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_module_set_name: assertion 'G_IS_TYPE_MODULE (module)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

4103086391 is a unique identifier of the camera, which I am using as window name, hence its appearance in the error logs.

The code runs (albeit with other errors) flawlessly if I don't use imshow, as I can write the frames from both threads using imwrite.

Comment: can you try to use cv::namedWindow in the main thread before, once for each desired window?

Comment: Tried already. I get a different set of errors. Could try that way, but I think that defining windows in each thread is way more structured and easy to mantain and develop.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?